# slow load speed of data from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I've got a moderate size MySQL database with about 30 tables, some of which are 10 million records, some 100 million. The `mysqldump` of all the tables (into separate files) is fairly fast, takes maybe 20 minutes. It generates about 15GB of data. The largest dumped files are in the 2GB range.

When I load the data into MySQL on another box, a six-core, 8GB machine, it takes forever. Easily 12 clock hours or more.

I'm just running the mysql client to load the file, i.e.

```
mysql database < footable.sql
```

directly with the file directly out of mysqldump

```
mysqldump database foo > footable.sql
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong. Where do I start so it can finish in a reasonable time?

I'm not using any switches on either the dump or the load.

Comment: You can also desactivate the binary logging during the load of your dump

Answer (score 25):

Take these some points in your consideration they may help you in case of generating the dump and restoring it.

1. Use `Extended inserts` in dumps.
2. Dump with `--tab` format so you can use `mysqlimport`, which is faster than `mysql < dumpfile`.
3. Import with multiple threads, one for each table.
4. Use a different database engine if possible. importing into a heavily transactional engine like innodb is awfully slow. Inserting into a non-transactional engine like MyISAM is much much faster.
5. Turn off foreign key checks and turn on auto-commit.
6. If you are importing to innodb the single most effective thing you can do is to put `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` in your my.cnf, temporarily while the import is running. you can put it back to 1 if you need ACID

Give it a try..

Comment: Your hint with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` saved my day. Importing a 600 MB dump (as a single big transaction) would have needed 6 hours, but with this temporary setting, it was done in 30 minutes!

Comment: The things you wish you knew before trying to load an 80gig database from a dump 4 days after hitting 'enter'... :)

Answer (score 8):

I have been dealing a lot with this lately. You can definitely improve import performance by doing the imports in parallel. Most of the slowdown is I/O based, but you can still get a 40% improvement by dumping into tables and then importing them say 4 at a time.

You can do this with xargs like this:

```
ls *.sql -1c | xargs -P4 -I tbl_name sh -c "mysql --user=username --password database < tbl_name"
```

having the files gzipped before pushing them to mysql doesn't slow anything down mostly because of the lowered I/O. My tables were compressed up to about 10:1, so it saves a lot of disk space.

I've found that on 4 core machines, using 4 processes is optimal, although only marginally better than using 3. If you have SSDs or a fast RAID, you will likely scale better.

Some other things to note. If you have 4k sector drives, make sure you have `key_cache_block_size=4096` and `myisam_block_size=4K`.

If you are using MyISAM tables, set the `myisam_repair_threads = 2` or higher. This will allow your extra cores to help rebuild indexes.

Make sure you aren't swapping at all. If you are, reduce the size of the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

I think I got some speedup with innnodb by these options too:

```
innodb_flush_method= O_DIRECT (LINUX ONLY)
innodb_flush_log_at_commit = 0
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_checksums=0
```

(the last three I didn't test extensively - I think I found them as suggestions on the internets.) Note that the `innodb_flush_log_at_commit=0` can result in corruption with mysql crashing or power going out.

Comment: Greg, welcome to the site and thank you for your answer. Could you provide some sources or reasoning for your suggestions on `*_block_size` and `myisam_repair_threads`? Also, not sure we should offer advice to tune variables based on 'suggestions from the internets' :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Abdul's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13447/180) answer, I'd like to stress the importance of the [`--disable-keys`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys) option, which turns off keys until all the data is loaded for a table. This option is enabled as part of the [`--opt`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) toggle, which is enabled by default, but thought it important to point out.

If you do not skip keys during the inserts, then each row inserted will rebuild the index. An extremely slow process.

Comment: is --disable-keys part of the mysqldump? or the reload?

Comment: it will be added in the dump file

Comment: `--opt` is on by default

Comment: `This option is effective only for nonunique indexes of MyISAM tables. It has no effect for other tables`

Answer (score 5):

If you mainly have MyISAM tables, you should increase the [bulk insert buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size). Here is what the MySQL Documentation says on setting [bulk_insert_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size):

> MyISAM uses a special tree-like cache to make bulk inserts faster for
>   INSERT ... SELECT, INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ..., and LOAD DATA
>   INFILE when adding data to nonempty tables. This variable limits the
>   size of the cache tree in bytes per thread. Setting it to 0 disables
>   this optimization. The default value is 8MB.

There are two things you need to do

1) Add it to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
```

2) Set the global value for it

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;
```

If you do not have the privilege to set bulk_insert_buffer_size globally, then do this

```
service mysql restart
```

Of course, this is not for InnoDB.

From another angle, whether the tables are InnoDB or MyISAM, if the indexes are larger that than the table, you may have too many indexes. I usually guestimate that a reload of a MyISAM mysqldump should take 3 times as long as the mysqldump took to make. I also
guestimate that a reload of a InnoDB mysqldump should take 4 times as long as the mysqldump took to make.

If you are exceeding the 4:1 ratio for reloading a mysqldump, you definitely have one of two problems:

- too many indexes
- indexes just too large due to large columns

You can measure the size of your data by storage engine with this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine",
CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(
FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(
FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size" FROM
(SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,
SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM
information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') AND
engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
(SELECT 3 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;
```

See if the indexes are alsmost as big as the data or even bigger

You may also consider disabling binary logging like this:

```
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;" > footable.sql
mysqldump --databases foo >> footable.sql
```

before reloading the script

Comment: I don't know how many times you've saved my day but it sure has been a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you bypass the filesystem altogether and just pipe the output of mysqldump directly into a MySQL process you should see noticeable performance improvements.  How much ultimately depends on the type of disk drive you are using but I rarely use dump files anymore regardless of database size for this reason alone.

```
mysqldump -uxxx -pxxx -hxxx --single-transaction --routines --databases dbname | mysql -uyyy -pyyy -hyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

According to my experiences, the hard drive is the bottleneck. Forget spinning disks. SSD is better, but by far the best is to perform this in RAM - if you have enough to hold the entire database for a short while. Roughly:

1. stop mysqld
2. move away existing contents of /var/lib/mysql
3. create an empty /var/lib/mysql dir
4. mount -t tmpfs -o size=32g tmpfs /var/lib/mysql (adjust the size)
5. create an empty db (e.g. mysql_install_db, or restore previous contents)
6. start mysqld
7. import
8. stop mysqld
9. copy /var/lib/mysql to mysql2
10. umount mysql; rmdir mysql
11. move mysql2 to mysql
12. start mysqld, be happy

For me, a dump of ~10G (/var/lib/mysql consuming ~20G) can be imported in about 35 minutes (mydumper/myloader), 45 minutes (mysqldump --tab/mysqlimport), 50 minutes (mysqldump/mysql), on a 2x6-core 3.2GHz Xeon.

If you don't have enough RAM in a single machine, but have several computers next to each other with fast network, it would be interesting to see if their RAMs can be joined with nbd (network block device). Or, with innodb_file_per_table, you can probably repeat the above process for each table.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried storing the mysql datadir in RAM to compare it with an SSD (SSDSC2BB48 for those interested) for a 2 GB database. The results were IDENTICAL, both of them took 207-209 seconds. Considering the fact that you also have to start/stop mysql and copy the directories, using a RAM disk instead of the SSD was much slower in my case

Comment: If it took you ~3-4 minutes, I guess you have significantly smaller database than what this topic is about. It'd be interesting to hear about your experiences with similarly large databases than the ones mentioned in this topic.